# Scaleable way to host PHP web service?

Tags: web-hosting, php, scalability

This is my first time working on a project like this, and i'm not sure where to turn next or how i should go about launching.

Currently the site consists of PHP and html files in a "**/public_html**" directory with godaddy hosting.

I don't know much about bandwidth or server requirements needed. But clients create directories (unknowingly) and users can view the content generated for the specific clients directory. I estimate to start, there would be around 25 clients with anywhere from 2-30 active users viewing the clients generated pages.

**How can i make this scaleable?** So i won't have to worry about switching hosts? Do i just go with a typical godaddy (or any other hosting company) plan? Im new to this.

Comment: Sorry but questions regarding recommendations on web hosting is considered off topic due to the fact they are opinionated and attract spam. If you don't find a suitable answer in the linked question its because someone hasn't left one catered for reselling hosting as of yet, your more than welcome to ask us in our chat channel where members check regularly.

Comment: alright, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at a VPS (Virtual Private Server, sometimes referred to as a blade), which basically is a large server shared with multiple users, but in a way they can not interfere with eachother (one could be using 100% of its CPU without you knowing so).

They can easily be upgraded, you can add memory, or cpu, or bandwidth, or all of it, just by going to your controlpanel and click upgrade.

Comment: any suggestions as far as hosts go?

Comment: I'm dutch and my experience so far is mostly with transip.nl (which I like), I don't know if GoDaddy does something similar (probably).

Comment: The one comment I have is "choose your host carefully grasshopper".  Once your site has grown to a certain size, it becomes very complex to move to a new host.